# How can i test django rest framework class based views

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have this code

```
class SnippetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    def get_data():
        pass
```

Now i want to test get_data

I want to do something like

```
view = SnippetList.as_view()
actual = view.get_data()
expected = "test"
```

But i am not sure how can i make view object

I get this error

```
*** AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_data'
```

Comment: How is `get_data` called originally?

Comment: @RahulGupta inside the 'get' method , `self.get_data`

Comment: Please post the code for `get_data`function and the place where it is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find this function useful(found [here](http://django-downloadview.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing.html#django_downloadview.test.setup_view)):

```
def setup_view(view, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """Mimic as_view() returned callable, but returns view instance.
    args and kwargs are the same you would pass to ``reverse()``
    """
    view.request = request
    view.args = args
    view.kwargs = kwargs
    return view
```

You can use it like this:

```
view = setup_view(
    views.DynamicStorageDownloadView(),
    django.test.RequestFactory().get('/fake-url'),
    path='dummy path')
path = view.get_path()
self.assertEqual(path, 'DUMMY PATH')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like as_view() return function, but not an object.
Could you please try this code?

```
view = SnippetList.as_view()(request)
```